# How to get array object in object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The following is a sample document in my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "0001",
    "name" : "Meteor",
    "categoryId" : "001",
    "period" : 4,
    "price" : 68,
    "des" : "សម្រាប់ការចុះឈ្មោះ៥០នាក់ដំបូង",
    "paymentMethod" : {
        "oneMonth" : 100,
        "threeMonth" : 150,
        "sixMonth" : 375,
        "year" : 750,
        "midTerm" : 200,
        "term" : 750
    }
}
```

How do I get the values from `"paymentMethod"` key to show in a selectbox?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<select>
    {{#each methods}}
        <option value={{value}}>{{method}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>

Template.body.helpers({
    methods: function () {
        var ArrMethods = [];
        var objPayment = MyCollection.findOne({_id: '0001'});
        $.each(objPayment.paymentMethod, function (key, value) {
            ArrMethods.push({
                method: key,
                value : value
            });
        });
        return ArrMethods;
    }
});
```

Comment: @SylvainLeroux the question is straightforward, so the answer is. the other thing is the code i provided is readable(code speaks). Question is in the context of *how* (code) instead of *why* (fair enough if questioner or answerer ask for).

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.name.helpers({
    'selectOptions': function () {
        var obj = MyCollection.findOne({_id: '0001'});
        var options = obj && obj.paymentMethod;
        var helperReadyOptions = [];
        Object.keys(options).forEach(function(key) {
            helperReadyOptions.push({
                label: key,
                value: options[key]
            });
        });
        return helperReadyOptions;
    }
});

<template name="name">
    <select>
        {{#each selectOptions}}
            <option value="{{value}}">{{label}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider adding some comments in you code and/or adding some explanations to your answers about _why_ you did it this way.